# chamar .keypress(e) somente se .change(e) estiver OK

Tags: jquery

Olá,

Preciso de uma ajuda. Eu tenho um campo `input[type=text]` que eu tenho uns gatilhos nele, um gatilho `.change` e um `.keypress` .

Porém, no `.change` eu chamo uma função de validação do campo e no `.keypress` eu verifico se o usuário apertou `ENTER` para eu salvar no banco o valor desse campo.

Com isso, quando o usuário digita algum valor nesse campo e esse campo não está de acordo, a função do `.change` aponta o problema, mas mesmo assim o `.keypress` é acionado e salva a linha com o valor incorreto.

Tem alguma forma de eu não precisar chamar a validação no `.keypress` também?

Exemplo:

```
$("campo").change(function(e){
       valida_campo(this);
}).keypress(function(e){
    if(e.which == 13) {
       salva_campo(this);
    }
});
```

Comment: O evento `change` não dispara quando inseres texto. Esse `valida_campo` não devia ser corrido no caso de `Enter`? Esse `valida_campo_ é assíncrono?

Comment: Não é assincrono. Ele dispara os 2 gatilhos quando aperta ENTER.

Comment: Não vejo a necessidade de você utilizar o evento `change`, sendo que no `keypress` já faz o que você precisa. Use apenas o `keypress` para validar e salvar o campo, ou seja, só irá salvar, depois que o resultado da função `valida_campo` for `true`, por exemplo.

Comment: Concordo com o @DouglasGarrido, poderia ser algo assim: https://jsfiddle.net/7hxues6L/

Comment: Exatamente como o @Sergio demonstrou.

Comment: Ok, entendi o posicionamento de vocês e também concordo. Problema resolvido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O evento change não dispara quando inseres texto, assim se queres que o `valida_campo` seja corrido antes de _salva_campo_ ser corrido, e garantir que `salva_campo` não é corrido caso `valida_campo` falhar, então podes fazer assim, removendo a lógica do `change`:

```
$("input").keypress(function(e) {
    var valido = valida_campo(this);
    if (valido && e.which == 13) {
        salva_campo(this);
    }
});
```